# Why is destructor being called more than enough when using an object as key in a multimap

Tags: c++, class, destructor, multimap

I am using an object as a key in a multimap as follows. I only have 1 instance of class Data: `Data d1(1,2)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Data{
    public:
        static int counter;
        Data(int x = 0, int y = 0):_x(x),_y(y){counter += 1; cout <<"constructor call " << counter << endl;}

        virtual ~Data()
        {
            counter -= 1;
            cout <<"calling destructor " << counter <<  endl;
        }

        bool operator<(const Data & right) const{
            return _x < right._x && _y < right._y;
        }
    private:
        int _x;
        int _y;
};

int Data::counter = 0;

int main()
{
 multimap<Data, string> m_map;

 Data d1(1,2);
 m_map.insert(make_pair(d1, "1"));

 return 0;   
}
```

---

In the output the destructor is being called 3 times.

```
constructor call 1
calling destructor 0
calling destructor -1
calling destructor -2
```

Comment: Add logging to a copy constructor too

Comment: .. and the move constructor.  Moved-from objects are still destroyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have more than one instance.

```
class Data {
public:
    static int counter;
    Data(int x = 0, int y = 0) :_x(x), _y(y) { counter += 1; cout << "constructor call " << counter << endl; }
    Data(const Data & other) :_x(other._x), _y(other._y) { counter += 1; cout << "copy constructor call " << counter << endl; }

    virtual ~Data()
    {
        counter -= 1;
        cout << "calling destructor " << counter << endl;
    }

    bool operator<(const Data & right) const {
        return _x < right._x && _y < right._y;
    }
private:
    int _x;
    int _y;
};
```

This will show the copy constructor being called too.

Comment: yes that's right thank you @doctorlove
constructor call 1
copy constructor call 2
copy constructor call 3
calling destructor 2
calling destructor 1
calling destructor 0

Comment: Look up rule of three/five/zero - if you write a destructor you often have to consider copy cons, and assignment (and moves)

Comment: When I use the move constructor . It also gets called. As @Sam Varshavchik I have to trace it.

Comment: 'constructor call 1
copy constructor call 2
move constructor call 3
calling destructor 2
calling destructor 1
calling destructor 0'

Answer (score 2):

The other two destructor calls are destroying temporary objects that were initially copy-constructed. Add an explicit copy constructor to the object, and you'll see it getting invoked.

To figure out why the copy-constructor get called, observe that the parameter to `std::map::insert` is a `std::pair`. Now consider, for a moment, what must actually happen in order for this sequence of events to take place to actually occur: a `std::pair` getting constructed, containing your object; and for this `std::pair` to get inserted into the actual map.

For an additional level of insight and understanding, use a debugger to set a breakpoint in your copy-constructor, and examine the stack trace each time the breakpoint gets hit.